# Why Array is values and how it can be implemented in Golang?

Tags: arrays, go

As [Array doc in golang](https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro) says:

> Go's arrays are values. An array variable denotes the entire array; it is not a pointer to the first array element (as would be the case in C). This means that when you assign or pass around an array value you will make a copy of its contents.

As we all know,when an array is created,a piece of memory will be allocated to save values included in this array:
[image]
<sub>(source: [golang.org](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals_slice-array.png))</sub>

And the array name in C points to the first memory address,then it can calculate the address of given array index and modify or read the value of this index.But this doc says golang implementation is different from this.

I'm confused that what advantages do golang way have and how it can implement as its current way.Anyone can tell me about this,thanks very much!

Comment: You should have read up further -- to part explaining slices and how they build up on the concept of the array.  That said, arrays are useful sometimes, and what slices to for arrays in Go, in C do arrays-to-pointer coercion and techniques like passing the array and a count together.

Comment: Actually, I'd recommend reading [this](https://blog.golang.org/slices) as IMO it explains how arrays and slices go along more clearly.

Comment: @kostix,thanks for your guide,I have read this doc and it says "The data associated with an array is just that: an array of elements." what does it mean? Is `length` also its field?And if the array have `length` and `data`,it also a struct?

Comment: No, the length is known from the type of a particular array, so it is not kept in array *values* (contrary to, say, slices and strings) — simply because the compiler always knows it from the array's type.

Answer (score 1):

In Golang there are 3 types to work on arrays. (T = any type in Go like string, int, etc) (n = natural numbers)

1. array (fixed array) [n]T

> ```
> var array [5]int
> array[1] = 2
> fmt.Println(array)
> ```

2. slice (dynamic array) []T
3. map (associative array) [T]T

Go's arrays are values. Because you just work with values and keys are sequence of natural numbers. Golang saves arrays length in arrays type and Because of that arrays are fixed (after declaration) and Golang can create a piece of memory with arrays length.

Also you can ask about Golang infrastructure here. https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Questions

Comment: If array type have length field and data field,is it also a struct?

Comment: Struct is a different one. There are 4 types to work on data structure array, slice, map and struct.

Comment: You can ask about Golang infrastructure here. https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Questions

Answer (score 0):

If we take this example from the doc

```
var a [4]int
a[0] = 1
i := a[0]
// i == 1
```

Based on the doc, they are saying that in C if you would access var `a`, you'd get a pointer to `a[0]`.

I'm not sure about the advantage or what you mean with implementing it

Comment: the doc says that "The data associated with an array is just that: an array of elements.",what does this mean,Is length also its field.If array type have length field and data field,is it a struct?